# Adding calculated fields to Google-Sheets form results

Tags: google-sheets

I'm taking data with a Google Spreadsheet form.
But for grouping puproses I want to add a column in the result-table with the weeknumber.

I also want a calculated field in my result-table.

Is this even possible? And what is the best way to accomplish this?

edit: hope this works.
this is the spreadsheet generated (and filled) by the form. Not the real one, just an example one.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXqNiP9EIx3lA0ND1ysFitfN9QVEGVXY2SI5cHF57oA/edit?usp=sharing

As said, I would like to be able to add a weeknumber field, and get a calculated field (total (Amount * Price))

The Calculated field can propabably be achieved with a query on a second Sheet. But I can't use a 'Weeknum()' in a query and group by it.

Comment: It sounds very possible. Please share a test sheet with dummy data and expected results.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I editted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the week number, paste in the first cell of the column of your choice (e.g. `E2`):

  `=arrayformula(WEEKNUM(A2:A))`
- For the calculated product field, e.g. in `F2`:

  `=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C*D2:D)`

The results of the array formulas will automatically update when new form responses come into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution. I didn't know 'arrayformula', so I was populating each cell with a normal function. Only to have it removed on every new form entry.